What is the appropriate statistical test in this scenario?
I work with a particular genus of plants where there have been many instances where what was once considered a species is now considered to be a synonym of another species. I am interested in understanding why this happens and so am looking at the criteria that were used to designate them as species in the first place. There are four broad criteria - I through IV. What I want to know is which of these criteria result(s) in stable species status and which result(s) in unstable species status (that is, being designated as a synonym). I have data for over 1000 species. The problems is that each species could have had one or more criteria to call it a new species, so that the data can look like this:

and so on for >1000 species.
In other words, not all four criteria were used in all cases. There is no quantitative data. It's all binary - Yes/No. I'm thinking maybe some kind of logistic regression? Not sure what though. Maybe I am overthinking it and there could be a straightforward test...
Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Look under binary classifier. A broad topic, which includes Decision Trees, Random Forests. Neural Nets, and yes, Logistic Regression. As far as which is "best" in your case, I defer to other's expertise.

Thank you, @jginestet. My research question is: is there an association between a stable species status and the criterion or combination of criteria used when the species was discovered? If so, what are these criteria? Sometimes, I think even a simple chi square test of independence will do the job, but then I am concerned about the lack of independence between say, cases where only Crit-I was used and others where Crit-I and Crit-II were used. I will check the Binary Classifier tag too, but am hoping that someone would have some insights here on how to deal with this lack of independence.
